# Group contours with the same y value

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have been following a tutorial about computer vision and doing a little project to read the time from a game. The game time is formatted h:m. So far I got the h and m figured out using findContours, but I'm having trouble isolating the colon as the character shape is not continuous. Because of this when I try to matchTemplate the code freaks out and starts to use the dot to match to all the other digits.

Are there ways to group the contours by X?

Here are simplified code to get the reference digits, the code to get digits from the screen is basically the same.

```
    refCnts = cv2.findContours(ref.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    refCnts = imutils.grab_contours(refCnts)
    refCnts = contours.sort_contours(refCnts, method="left-to-right")[0]

    digits = {}

    # loop over the OCR-A reference contours
    for (i, c) in enumerate(refCnts):
        # compute the bounding box for the digit, extract it, and resize
        # it to a fixed size
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        roi = ref[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, (10, 13))
        digits[i] = roi
```

Im new to python and opencv. Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.

Here is the reference image I'm using:

[image]

Here is the input image I'm trying to read:

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach an input image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use `findCountours`? Because there are better suited methods for such problems. For instance, you can use *template matching* as shown below:

These are `input`, `template` (cut out from your reference image), and `output` images:

[image: input.png]

[image: template.png]

[image: output.png]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

# Read the input image & convert to grayscale
input_rgb = cv2.imread('input.png')
input_gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

# Read the template (Using 0 to read image in grayscale mode)
template = cv2.imread('template.png', 0) 

# Perform template matching - more on this here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d
res = cv2.matchTemplate(input_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 

# Store the coordinates of matched area 
# found the threshold value of .56 using trial & error using the input image - might be different in your game
lc = np.where( res >= 0.56)  

# Draw a rectangle around the matched region
# I used the width and height of the template image but in practice you need to use a better method to accomplish this
w, h = template.shape[::-1] 
for pt in zip(*lc[::-1]): 
    cv2.rectangle(input_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 1)

# display output
cv2.imshow('Detected',input_rgb) 
# cv2.imwrite('output.png', input_rgb)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You may also look into text detection & recognition using openCV.